# How to tree-shake my `tsc` compiled `utils` npm package when importing in a CRA app?

Tags: node.js, webpack, create-react-app, tsc, tree-shaking

I want to get this to work, but I'm not sure where to start. I control two npm packages:

1. A frontend CRA app (I'll call it `FE`)
2. An `utils` package used for sharing code between `FE` and some other packages that are not in focus here

The `FE` package depends on `utils` (includes it as a dependency in `package.json`), but `utils` also contains some node-specific code that cannot run in the browser (this code is imported by two other packages, but not `FE`). Up until recently everything worked fine, but after I upgraded CRA (react-scripts) to from v4 to v5 (in `FE` package), which also switched to webpack v5 under the hood, my CRA app suddenly crashes in browser when loading the bundle (using CRA dev server), because it now includes and runs non-browser-compatible node.js code. This code is meant for other packages, and should not be loaded in `FE` package.

I understand that this is a consequence of `utils` exporting all of its code via `index.ts` and `FE` importing specific functions from there - although I have no idea why it worked on react-scripts v4 and now it suddenly doesn't on v5. And I know that I could likely get around this by exporting and importing all of my utils directly as separate modules. But I would much rather dynamically tree-shake anything I'm not importing automatically. **I use [CRACO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) in my CRA app (`FE`), so I do have the ability to modify its webpack config.**

**So my question is: How can I set up this tree-shaking, so `FE` no longer includes utility functions it does not use in its bundle?** Like I said, I don't really know where to begin. I am also interested in finding out what about upgrading to react-scripts v5 made it break, and if it may be possible to simply replaicate v4 behaviour.

`utils` package is built simply via `tsc` - it does not include webpack

```json
// scripts section from utils/package.json
"scripts": {
  "start": "yarn build",
  "build": "tsc",
  "watch": "tsc -w",
  "postinstall": "patch-package",
  "prepare": "yarn build",
  "test": "jest"
}
```

Here is `tsconfig.json` of the `utils` package:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6" ,
    "module": "commonjs" ,
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",

    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,

    "baseUrl": "../",
    "paths": {
      "@schema": ["schema/index"],
      "@schema/*": ["schema/*"]
    },
    
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["types/**/*", "**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack@4 automatically polyfilled a lot of nodejs modules when the bundle ran in browser environment. You have to do this manually in webpack@5.

Check this link, it is a good place to start: [webpack@5 gist](https://gist.github.com/ef4/d2cf5672a93cf241fd47c020b9b3066a)

I know this is not tree-shaking, but depends on your modules' layout tree-shaking may not even work without further code modifications.